# Using Route53 to serve https request for my s3 bucket via cludfront distribituin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I spent almost 3 days with trial and error , documention and more but not sloving my issue. i pretty sure i do same mistake over and over again. please try read my steps and figure out why i cant using my domain in url in order to get my site.

1. I upload my FE static files into s3 bucket as website.
   The url is working well at http://myBucket.s3-website.il-central-1.amazonaws.com/
2. route 53: I bought a new domain "myDomain.net" from aws route 53
3. route 53: created new host zone and from the record of type ns , I
   copied the values there to my clipboard
4. route53:

```
   registred domain => actions => edit name servers 
   => paste the values from prev state
```

example : ns-xyz.awsdns-ab.net (and all others)
now all name server of my domain are the same as the ns record in my
hostzone

5. certificate manager: I created public certificate in the US East (N.
   Virginia) region and awaited to status: Issued
6. ACM and route53: in the new ssl certificate i clicked on "create
   records in route53" button and I created CNAME record in my hostzone
   value : someToken.someString.acm-validations.aws.
7. cloudFront:
   create distribution => origin domain it shows me an autocomplete to
   my s3 bucket as : myDomain.s3.il-central-1.amazonaws.com
   I know it should use the s3 URL format as:
   "http://myBucket.s3-website.my-region.amazonaws.com/"
   So I pasted the the s3 URL format but now in protocl it shows HTTP
   only option.

```
    => Viewer protocol policy i change to Redirect HTTP to HTTPS 
    => Do not enable security protections 
    => Alternate domain name (CNAME) - optional i set as myDomain.net 
    => Custom SSL certificate - optional - the certificate created in 
       step 5 Click on the create distribution button and test the new 
       URL "https://someId.cloudfront.net" and it works well.
```

now it seems my s3 and Cloudfront are connected I guess

8.route53 :

```
  create record => record name i keep it blank (my alternate name is 
  same as my region ...maybe its a mistake and i shouldn't create 
  alternate name?) 
  =>record type - A 
  => alias -> alias to cloud front distribution -> 
     someId.cloudfront.net clicked on create record
```

In the begining i tried to navigate to "myDomain.net" with https or event http and nothing happens i got DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN (checked in incognito also )

after about 6-7 hours it worked , I get access to my site with my domain as URL but after a few minutes I got

Web Page Blocked!
You have tried to access a web page which belongs to a category that is blocked.

what i did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you reviewed your bucket's privacy policies after the cloudFront configuration?

Your s3 bucket should:

- block all the public access
- have properly bucket policy

In order to block the public access go to the bucket's Permissions tab and select the `Edit` button below the `Block Public access` section, then check block all public access and save.

The second step is configure the bucket policy, you can copy the configuration from the cloudfront distribution menu.

- Select the CF distribution created from the CF menu
- click on `Origins` tab, select the S3 origin then click `Edit`
- choose `Origin Access Control Setting` in the Origin Access Section
- If there is no Origin access control create a new one, otherwise select the one related to your s3 bucket
- Copy the bucket policy by clicking on `Copy Policy` button then select the `Go to s3 bucket permissions` link
- In the new tab edit the Bucket policy by copying the policy you got from  cloudfront
- Remember to save both the bucket and the CF page

After those settings the webpage should be reachable.
Hope this will help.

Comment: can u share documentaion of that , i didnt see the reuqest of changing the bucket policy . anyway i edit the question due to i did manage to navigate to my site after 6-7 hours but later i got blocked from the browswer

Comment: If you Just want it to works follow the steps at this link https://medium.com/tide-engineering-team/block-public-s3-bucket-access-with-cloudfront-oai-dc7f442f42a5 otherwise I suggest to use both AWS S3 and Cloudfront documentation in order to acknowledge the meaning of bucket policies and security access.

Comment: If your origin is an Amazon S3 bucket configured as a website endpoint, you must set it up with CloudFront as a custom origin. That means you can't use OAC (or OAI). However, you can restrict access to a custom origin by setting up custom headers and configuring the origin to require them. For more information, see Restricting access to files on custom origins.

anyway i couldnt find any docs says that i need block public access to my bucket. how does it related to that my region response with DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: In order to determine if the problem is truly related to your Route53 configuration (which probably is) I suggest to remove the domain configuration from cloudfront and use the cloudfront provided url to check if the website on the bucket is accessible.
Once you have checked I suggest to review this article https://dev.to/aws-builders/guide-to-hosting-a-static-website-on-aws-using-s3-cloudfront-and-route53-with-just-7-steps-220b which explain how to configure a static website hosting on AWS. I still encourage you to use the OAC instead of the public bucket due to security reasons.

Comment: as far as i follows i did extacly as in the https://d35cuutd5a2rxq.cloudfront.net/ 
anyway the url i got from cloudfront is working perfect and my domain site work once in my desktop and mobile and after a while it stop works but now it works on my second laptop